# Function not going to next steps

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, command

I have created below function, when I am executing this function with shell script it completed fine but not going to next steps

```
 time_check()    
{     
. /u01/scripts/${1}.env     
export create_env_log=${logs}/create_env_log_${dts}.log     
echo 'STime:' date +%s > ${create_env_log}    
  "$@"    
echo 'ETime:' date +%s >> ${create_env_log}    

export st_time= grep -i STime ${create_env_log} |cut -d':' -f2       
export en_time= grep -i ETime ${create_env_log} |cut -d':' -f2      
export exectime=$((en_time-st_time))      
echo 'Completed in ' printf '%dd:%dh:%dm:%ds\n' $(($exectime/86400)) $(($exectime%86400/3600)) $(($exectime%3600/60)) $(($exectime%60))  >>  ${create_env_log}
Totexectime=$((Totexectime+exectime))      
echo 'This step completed in : 'printf '%dd:%dh:%dm:%ds\n' $(($exectime/86400)) $(($exectime%86400/3600)) $(($exectime%3600/60)) $(($exectime%60))      
}
```

In my shell script I have placed below lines:

`time_check /u01/scripts/copy.sh ${1} | tee ${copylog}`

`echo "Starting Next Steps now:" >>> Issue here , not coming to this phase.`

I am getting some output like this:

This step completed in : 0d:0h:12m:9s ( which is output of time_check /u01/scripts/copy.sh )

Comment: Sorry for bad formatted output , please note I have to remove few ` becuase I unable to do it as it wont allow me to post.

Comment: write `set -x` on top of your script and run again and check the output

Comment: Acknowledged . Thanks for your quick response . I will check that and update the result. Thanks

Comment: Place `echo "var 1=${1}"` before calling `time_check` and in the function before sourcing `/u01/scripts/${1}.env`. Do you want to source `/u01/scripts//u01/scripts/copy.sh.env` ?

Comment: Can you debug with something like `time_check sleep 3; echo "After sleep"`

Comment: I have fixed it using a success_check() function , when this success_check returns 0 it progress ahead . Thanks all for your time and advise.

Comment: Anyone can guide how can I call value of Totexectime outside this function say in shell script. Thanks in advance.