# How to call value from a function to shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, command

For my requirement I want to use below time variable exectime outside this function and want to call it from shell script.
Could anyone please help how to call it from shell script

> time_check()     {      . /u01/scripts/${1}.env      export
>   create_env_log=${logs}/create_env_log_${dts}.log      echo 'STime:'
>   date +%s > ${create_env_log}       "$@"     echo 'ETime:' date +%s >>
>   ${create_env_log}
>
> export st_time= grep -i STime ${create_env_log} |cut -d':' -f2
>   export en_time= grep -i ETime ${create_env_log} |cut -d':' -f2
>   export exectime=$((en_time-st_time))
>   exectime=$((Totexectime+exectime))
>          }

Comment: Your code needs to be reformatted completely; there is no way we can guess where the line breaks should be. Please [edit] your question; code should be indented at least four spaces. See also [Markdown help.](/editing-help)

Comment: You have posted about the same in https://stackoverflow.com/q/51805468/3220113 so close this one.  Please look how your question was formatted and try to make this question more clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function not going to next steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805468/function-not-going-to-next-steps)

Answer (score 0):

To call up a function as a command in the shell, you would need to source the file containing it (similar to how you sourced `. /u01/scripts/${1}.env` in that function).

Example with `bash`:

```
function time_check() {
    . /u01/scripts/${1}.env
    export create_env_log=${logs}/create_env_log_${dts}.log
    echo 'STime:' date +%s > ${create_env_log} "$@"
    echo 'ETime:' date +%s >> ${create_env_log}

    export st_time= grep -i STime ${create_env_log} |cut -d':' -f2
    export en_time= grep -i ETime ${create_env_log} |cut -d':' -f2
    export exectime=$((en_time-st_time))
    exectime=$((Totexectime+exectime))
}
```

Your `.bashrc` file would then include the following line, so it gets sourced every time you start your shell:

```
. /path/to/function_file
```

This file can contain more than this one function, if you need.  So, you do not need to create several files to source multiple functions.